# Ubuntu software-center not loading

Tags: 14.04, software-center, gnome-terminal

I have tried loading up the software center in order to install some packages but it doesnt seem to open. I tried entering the following command in terminal:

```
software-center
```

and get the following error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/software-center: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. I am running on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling it using:

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

To no avail.

I also tried `sudo apt-get install -f` and received the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libntdb1 linux-headers-4.2.0-27 linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic python-ntdb
  python-support
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libglib2.0-dev (2.40.2-0ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libglib2.0-dev.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/libglib2.0-dev.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-dev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64:
 libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.4.1-2); however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libatk1.0-dev:
 libatk1.0-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.31.2); however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libatk1.0-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcairo2-dev:
 libcairo2-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev; however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcairo2-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                              No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                figured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.37.6); however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpango1.0-dev:
 libpango1.0-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.34.0); however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.
 libpango1.0-dev depends on libcairo2-dev (>= 1.12.10); however:
  Package libcairo2-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpango1.0-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtk-3-dev:
 libgtk-3-dev depends on libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.37.5); however:
  Package libglib2.0-dev is not configured yet.
 libgtk-3-dev depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.27.1); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev is not configured yet.
 libgtk-3-dev depends on libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.32.4); however:
  Package libpango1.0-dev is not configured yet.
 libgtk-3-dev depends on libatk1.0-dev (>= 2.7.5); however:
  Package libatk1.0-dev is not configured yet.
 libgtk-3-dev depends on libatk-bridge2.0-dev; however:
  Package libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgtk-3-dev depends on libcairo2-dev (>= 1.13.0~20140204); however:
  Package libcairo2-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgtk-3-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-support (1.0.15) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-support.postinst: 20: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-support.postinst: update-python-modules: not found
dpkg: error processing package python-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-wxversion (2.8.12.1+dfsg-2ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-wxversion.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-wxversion.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python-wxversion (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-wxgtk2.8:
 python-wxgtk2.8 depends on python-wxversion (>= 2.6.3.2.2-2); however:
  Package python-wxversion is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-wxgtk2.8 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up software-center (13.10-0ubuntu4.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/software-center.postinst: 8: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-center.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing package software-center (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-dev
 libatk-bridge2.0-dev:amd64
 libatk1.0-dev
 libcairo2-dev
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
 libpango1.0-dev
 libgtk-3-dev
 python-support
 python-wxversion
 python-wxgtk2.8
 software-center
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: @OP see if running `sudo apt-get install -f` does anything?

Comment: @OP also try running `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/software-center`

Answer (score 0):

All sorted. Turns out that some of the files in the default python package were missing. I used the following:

```
sudo apt-get -m --reinstall install python python-minimal dh-python
sudo apt-get -f install
```